# ng-boostrap not workingIf 'ngb-xx' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

Getting the message

> If 'ngb-xx' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of
>   this module

for every angular bootstrap components that i try

Setup process

```
npm install angular-cli
ng new project 
npm install 
npm install  --save bootstrap 
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

In app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http' ;

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap' ;

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms/src/directives/ng_form';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In .angular-cli.json

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css", 
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
```

Even try add npm install --save jquery  and in .angular-cli.json

```
  "scripts": [ 
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

in app.component.html add

```
  <ngb-tabset> 
      <ngb-tab title="test">
        <template ngbTabContent> 
            xxx ss
        </template>
      </ngb-tab>

      <ngb-tab title="test">
          <template ngbTabContent> 
              xxxs ss
          </template>
        </ngb-tab>
  </ngb-tabset>
<p>
  <ngb-alert [dismissible]="false">
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
  </ngb-alert>
</p>
```

the css seems to work but karma errors  and no js

> Failed: Template parse errors: 'ngb-tab' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'ngb-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'ngb-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>
> ("

ngalert only

> Failed: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'dismissible' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'ngb-alert'.
>
> 1. If 'ngb-alert' is an Angular component and it has 'dismissible' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'ngb-alert' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
> 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

Please help thanks

Looks like the problem seems to be comming from karma/jasmine setup

here is my karma.conf.js

// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: Your code is absolute fine , please share the code where you are using `ngb-tab`.

Comment: hi @VivekDoshi Thanks just added to the content

Comment: Hi @VivekDoshi Thanks for you answer demo puts me on the right track looks like the real problem here seems to be karma/ jasmine setup as app is working on its own but karma/jasmine is thowing the errors

Answer (score 4):

Issue is here :

```
npm install angular-cli
ng new project 
npm install 
npm install  --save bootstrap 
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

You Forgot to go in to the directory after project creation

```
npm install angular-cli
ng new project 
cd 'project' // <-------------- Here , you missed this
npm install 
npm install  --save bootstrap 
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

---

Another issue I can find here is `<template ngbTabContent>`

Change `<template ngbTabContent>` to `<ng-template ngbTabContent>` and also
`</template>` to `</ng-template>`.

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-demo)**

Comment: Looks like app is working on its own but karma/jasmine is Thowing errors may be i am missing a configuration for setting it up

Comment: if you modify you answer to help with the karma jasmine config i will accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

Finally find the problem

when installing and configuring modules dont forget to inset into test.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap' ; 
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot()
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```